# Can we enhance a thermal gradient by combining a dark surface and a shiny surface with an external glass layer?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, material-science, radiation, vacuum

I refer to the article at this site: 
http://solarcooking.wikia.com/wiki/Solar_Kettle-Thermos_Flask

As we know, dark surfaces absorb radiation (eg. solar water heater), while shiny surfaces reflect radiation (eg. vacuum flask).

Can we enhance the thermal gradient by combining these two types of surfaces on a container? In other words, can we increase the temperature within an evacuated container by using dark-outside-shiny-inside surfaces? On the contrary, can we decrease the temperature within an evacuated container by using shiny-outside-dark-inside surfaces?

If the answers are yes, does the Second Law of Thermodynamics still hold true? Why? What are the minimum/maximum temperatures that can be obtained in the containers?

Answer (score 0):

> can we increase the temperature within an evacuated container by using dark-outside-shiny-inside surfaces?

Yes, though I would not say it is because of increased temperature gradient.

If we have absorbing coating on the outside of the bottle, this will enhance energy absorbed per unit time from the solar radiation. This energy gets converted into thermal energy of the walls and subsequently of the water inside.

Reflective coating on the inside of the bottle ( not in mechanical contact with the absorptive cover) helps the water inside maintain its temperature, by decreasing the losses by radiation. Ideal material for this is metal, as it allows energy to come in through conduction, but prevents it from escaping by radiation.

Answer (score 0):

Dark materials heat things by capturing radiation, converting it to thermal energy of atoms, and *conducting* that thermal energy to other atoms. A reflective material can help maintain a temperature by reflecting radiation back the way it came, *insulating* one side from the other.

Both insulators and conductors work the same one way as the other. There is therefore no engineering solution that allows you to combine a radiative insulator with a thermal conductor in such a way that energy is magically moved from one side to the other but not back again. Any configuration of the two will result in either an overall thermal conductor or an overall radiative insulator. The classic metal vacuum bottle is great for maintaining temperature because it combines two *insulators:* the thermally-insulating vacuum wall and the radiation-insulating reflective bottle material. If there is more heat inside than outside, the bottle doesn't conduct or radiate it away very well; likewise, if there's more heat outside than inside, there's no good way for that heat to get into the bottle.

Adding a material that absorbs and conducts heat well, as most dark solids do, will help to *equalize* the temperature from one side of a container to the other... not imbalance it.